# Select div from list that has certain properties using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This seems so basic, but I am pulling hairs! I have a jQuery object of html elements and I would like to pick certain ones from it.

HTML:

```
<div data-id="1">1</div>
<div data-id="2">2</div>
<div data-id="3">3</div>
<div data-id="4" class="x">4</div>
```

JS:

```
var list = $('div');

// How can I filter through this list?
// pseudo

var id = 3; // (dynamic value)

var div3 = list.SELECTME('[data-id="' + id + '"]');
var div4 = list.SELECTME('.x');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are looking for using jQuery's [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```js
// using $ notation - $list indicates the variable contains a jQuery object
var $list = $('div');

var id = 3;

// utilize .filter to find items that match
var $div3 = $list.filter('[data-id="' + id + '"]');
var $div4 = $list.filter('.x');

console.log('div 3: ', $div3.text());
console.log('div 4: ', $div4.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="1">1</div>
<div data-id="2">2</div>
<div data-id="3">3</div>
<div data-id="4" class="x">4</div>
```

Comment: I even said "filter" in my comments.  Ugh!  Thank you so much!